# IIS6 + Mercurial, 404 when browsing repositories

Tags: mercurial, iis-6, windows-server-2003, isapi

Sorry for the cross-post, but I received no answer at serverfault.

I've set up a Mercurial server on a Win2k3 box with IIS6, using hgwebdir_wsgi, and it does seem to work until the point where I can see a nice list of my repositories in a browser, but if I try to browse any of them (that is, I click the name of the repo), then I get a 404 error.

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong? What log files or whatever should I check (I'm kinda new to IIS)? Thanks.

--

Some update:

The actual error code in the IIS logs is 404.0.2. A win32 error code of 2 simply means "file not found".

The event viewer is full of ISAPI errors like these:

```
The description for Event ID ( 4097 ) in Source ( ISAPI Filter or Extension ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Factory function '__FilterFactory__' failed, n/a.

Could not load all ISAPI filters for site/service.  Therefore startup aborted.    
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

The description for Event ID ( 4096 ) in Source ( ISAPI Filter or Extension ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Filter version function failed!, n/a.
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but [this page](http://blogs.iis.net/tomkmvp/archive/2009/04/27/troubleshooting-a-404.aspx) provides information on troubleshooting IIS 404 errors including how to configure IIS to include more info in the logs

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've already went through some of these steps. I've updated the question with some additional background info.